# FILESTREAM is enabled, but I get a message that it's not. Anyone able to help?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, filestream

I have been given the task of setting SharePoint Foundation 2010 up in work.  I have hit quite a few problems (see other questions I have posted), so I decided to start from scratch again.  I have installed SharePoint and SQL Server 2008.  Now I'm at the step of provisioning the BLOB storage and have the following three queries to run:

```
use [ContentDbName]
if not exists (select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name = '##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')create master key encryption by password = N'Admin Key Password !2#4'

use [ContentDbName]
if not exists (select groupname from sysfilegroups where groupname=N'RBSFilestreamProvider')alter database [ContentDbName] add filegroup RBSFilestreamProvider contains filestream

use [ContentDbName]
alter database [ContentDbName] add file (name = RBSFilestreamFile, filename = 'c:\Blobstore') to filegroup RBSFilestreamProvider
```

The first bit executes without a problem, but the second gives the message:

```
Msg 5591, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
FILESTREAM feature is disabled.
```

I have went into the Configuration Manager and checked that FILESTREAM was enabled, which it was.  I restarted the service and still get the same message.  Even restarting the server totally does not help.

What should I do?

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest double checking all the requirements for enabling FILESTREAM as per:

[How to: Enable FILESTREAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Step 11 worked for me